# can anyone explain inversion per byte?

Tags: hash, sha-3

I am designing the truncating block of SHA3 algorithm , there its given that first we need to do the inversion per byte of the 1600 bit output and then truncating it to give 512 bits output.

Can any one briefly explain this whole step of SHA3.

Comment: You should read the NIST specification: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf

Comment: Ya I have read it but i am not getting what inversion per byte is?

Comment: as someone who has implemented SHA-3 from scratch in code... I have no idea what byte inversion step you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, some people use the term **inversion per byte** for the conversion functions of section B1 of the standard, i.e. **h2b** and **b2h**, which convert from the unusual (i.e. different than as in SHA1, SHA2 ) NIST bit encoding to Hex bytes.

This is relevant only if you implement the API for hashing bit-string messages
with non-zero bit length mod 8.

The concluding paragraph of the 'Conversion Functions' section of FIPS 202  is: *The formal bit-reordering function that was specified in
[12] for the KECCAK submission to the SHA-3 competition gives
equivalent conversions when the message is byte-aligned, i.e.,
when n is a multiple of 8.*

If you work with byte messages this whole stuff adds some confusion but is not really necessary (and therefore it is no surprise that is not met often in actual implementations.)